# How to express a situation where someone puts others in a situation where others have to solve the problem

Tags: idiom-requests, phrase-requests, proverb-requests

Is there any proverb to express a situation where someone put others, without asking approval in advance, in a situation where others have to solve the problem?

He knows if he seeks for permission, then he will certainly be refused. So what he did was create a messy situation in the first place, and then ask for permission. 
That is what is happening now with the migrant crisis. The migrants illegally smuggled themselves to Europe and then ask for approval, but not the other way around.

Comment: Closely related: [Synonym for not taking personal responsibility](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/28014/synonym-for-not-taking-personal-responsibility)

Comment: It's a poor example, given that many people would say that the West created the problems in the first place by forcing or encouraging regime change throughout the Arab world. And that Germany exacerbated the migrant/refugee crisis by *encouraging* the first wave (which their aging population required) before slamming the door shut. Could you not change it to something less contentious?

Comment: Actually you are asking two questions. Those illegal immigrants didn't put others in a situation where others have to solve the problem. They just did what was necessary for them to survive. Please edit it to eliminate the ambiguity.

Comment: In your ill-chosen example, the refugees aren't at fault & if anything, they’re “guilty” of “[moving to the nuisance](https://books.google.com/books?id=QRTVBAAAQBAJ&pg=PT440&lpg=PT440&dq=%22moved+to+the+nuisance%22&source=bl&ots=3f7mi_gJ3I&sig=P680GdXUBizOQB0xy4sKVOvxyps&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjwu__7-LPLAhXrmoMKHQ_HCFsQ6AEIJDAB#v=onepage&q=%22moved%20to%20the%20nuisance%22&f=false)” [to escape real danger]. If you provided a legitimate example (& regardless?), I'd say “[you're making a nuisance of yourself](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/make-a-nuisance-of-yourself).”

Comment: *force the issue* is a close one.  *upset the applecart* perhaps.

Answer (score 1):

Without commenting on the validity of your example, I'll offer this quote:

**"It's easier to ask forgiveness than it is to get permission."** - [Grace Hopper](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Grace_Hopper).

Answer (score 0):

You may consider,

### [Pass the buck](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/pass+the+buck)

> *Fig.* to pass the blame (to someone else); to give the responsibility (to someone else).
>
> "Don't try to pass the buck! It's your fault, and everybody knows it."
>
> "Some people try to pass the buck whenever they can."