# What do you call someone who refuses to acknowledge their wrongdoing?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, adjectives, pejorative-language

There is a person in my current daily life who never admits his wrongs. He is always quick to blame others first and always believes that he is not wrong. Even when he is proven wrong, he still believes he shouldn't be sorry and isn't wrong.

Is there a single-word adjective to describe this behavior? If not, a better way to describe this person would also make do.

While `stubborn` and `irresponsible` fit, I feel like they don't tell the whole story. By this, I mean if I were to say to others that he is very stubborn and irresponsible, it is not implicitly implied that he blames others and never acknowledges his own fault.

Edit: I believe my question is different because the person will also never acknowledge their wrongdoing. On top of blaming others, even after it has been proven to be their fault, they will not admit wrong doing. So aside from blaming others, they refuse to acknowledge the possibility that they have committed a mistake.

Comment: This question may have some useful suggestions: [Synonym for not taking personal responsibility](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/28014/synonym-for-not-taking-personal-responsibility)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Sounds like a ***remorseless/unrepentant*** person.

ODO:

> **[remorseless](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/remorseless)**
>   *ADJECTIVE*
>
> **1** Without regret or guilt.
>
> ‘We're given to understand that because Charlie is tormented by guilt
>   that he somehow occupies a higher rung on the moral ladder than his
>   unrepentant, ***remorseless*** elder brother.’
>
> **[unrepentant](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/unrepentant)**
>   *ADJECTIVE*
>
> Showing no regret for one's wrongdoings.
>   ‘he was ***unrepentant*** and
>   said that his comments were completely accurate’

Answer (score 9):

The person might be incorrigible

> [**incorrigible**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/incorrigible): incapable of being corrected or amended

In context, the word usually implies that the person doesn't respond well to criticism or admit fault.

Answer (score 8):

He sounds like a **blameshifter**

> [blameshift](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/blameshift):
>
> (biblical) To blame another for one's own wrong-doing. Blameshifting can be caused by pointing the finger at another when trying to save one's skin. (Wiktionary)

Answer (score 6):

**shameless** ("insensible to disgrace", having no shame) per [MW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/shameless).

or

**unrepentant** (not exhibiting shame or remorse) per [MW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unrepentant).

also

**narcissist** (egoism) per [MW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/narcissist).

From [this prior answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/185835/what-do-you-call-someone-who-always-puts-blame-on-others), I particularly like **finger pointer**.

Answer (score 3):

Single word that comes to my mind is '**Nonchalant**' or '**Arrogant**'.
If I have to explain, I will say '**Expert in passing the buck**' or simply a '**buck passer**'.

Here are definitions according to Merriam-Webster.

> **Nonchalant**
>       :  having an air of easy unconcern or indifference
>
> **Arrogant**
>   :  showing an offensive attitude of superiority :  proceeding from or characterized by arrogance

Comment: Can you provide definitions for at least one of these suggestions, along with links to your sources?

Answer (score 0):

I think the concept or attitude you are trying to convey is complex and a single word which captures the message is therefore difficult.   I would suggest "arrogant", but as with your existing suggestions it may not sufficiently convey your message.

In my opinion, "Blameshifting" is not a word in common usage - certainly not here in Britain: I have never heard it used.

Answer (score 0):

If he calls attention to the same thing when someone else does it, the word would be [hypocrite](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hypocrite). Otherwise, [weasel](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/weasel) seems to have the connotation (when I hear it used) of falsely accusing someone in order to avoid being found out, though I don't see that specified in the definition.