# What is the word called once you go from ignorance to knowledgeable and still doing that negative action even though you know the truth

Tags: meaning

Example: coffee with milk. Coffee in it natural form is healthy, but when adding sugar and milk it become unhealthy. But the person still going to drink it knowing the truth.

Comment: @Jim JasonBassford Thank you for commenting. Please reserve the comment thread for *helping to improve the post*: friendly clarifying questions, suggestions for improving the question, relevant but transient information, and explanations of your actions. Please avoid discussion, debate, or giving answers in comments. A welcoming place for discussion of posts (or anything else) is our [English Language & Usage Chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95).

Answer (score 1):

**Persist**, although that word can have a positive connotation as well.
"She persisted despite the obstacles."  "He persisted despite knowing it was unhealthy."

See **incorrigible** and **unrepentant** in the similar [What do you call someone who refuses to acknowledge their wrongdoing?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/372103/what-do-you-call-someone-who-refuses-to-acknowledge-their-wrongdoing)

Answer (score 0):

One word for someone who is as you describe is **obstinate**. There are many others that you could use.

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/obstinate

https://www.freethesaurus.com/obstinate