# What is a single-word to describe a person who refuses to apologize or admit when they're wrong, especially when dealing with others?

Tags: single-word-requests

This is in regards to something objective that I am writing about unhealthy familial dynamics and how someone can move on in healthy ways. This is for a course I am taking.

What is a single-word to describe a family member who refuses to apologize or admit when they're wrong, especially when they've hurt or betrayed their family members? These slights could be trivial - hurt feelings, moderate - abuse/neglect, or extreme - criminal/exploitative.

Here are a few examples of each:

1. Trivial - A mother in her 60s hurts the feelings of her 40 year old daughter by calling her cute and/or adorable. Not only does the mother fail to notice that her daughter is hurt, but dismisses other people when she's told that her daughter was clearly hurt and that it's considered inappropriate to refer to someone in that age group as being cute or adorable. The mother immediately dismisses what is being said by stating that she didn't do anything wrong. When asked if anyone ever refered to her as being cute and/or adorable at 40 years old, she responds with no, but refuses to make any distinction.
2. Moderate - A father continually calls his daughter fat. She develops issues in regards to her self-image and it has a negative effect on her overall mental health. She falls behind at school. When others attempt to intervene, the father refuses to hold himself accountable or responsible and continues calling his daughter fat, even when he's aware of the consequences. Child Protective Services are brought in and the girl is removed from the home.
3. Extreme - A son uses his parents social security numbers to take out many large loans without their knowledge. He defaults on all of the loans, leaving his parents in millions of dollars in debt. He refuses to go forward and admit to the banks/federal agencies that he used his parents social security numbers without their consent, letting his parents take the fall.

I hope for objective answers.

Comment: I think the varying severity of the offenses you list would warrant different vocabulary treatments. One single word would not adequately serve for all three situations. Is one of these examples more relevant to your needs than the others?

Comment: There's also [What do you call someone who refuses to acknowledge their wrongdoing?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/372103/what-do-you-call-someone-who-refuses-to-acknowledge-their-wrongdoing/372197) Itself closed as a duplicate (this is a really old chestnut), so there are even more links there to other questions on more or less the same issue.